# if $x^TAx = 0$ for every $x$, then $A$ is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singularity

Let $A$ be some matrix,
If $x^TAx = 0$ for every vector $x$, then $A$ is singular.
How can I prove it?

Here is what I thought:

first of all, for every matrice $M$,
$$  x^T(M + M^T)x = x^TMx + x^TM^Tx = $$$$x^TMx + (x^TM^Tx)^T = x^TMx + x^TMx = 2(x^TMx)  $$
$\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}x^T(M + M^T)x = (x^TMx)$

now since $x^TMx = 0$ for every x , $ \frac{1}{2}x^T(M + M^T)x = 0$ for every $x$. thus, $M + M^T = 0 \rightarrow -M = M^T$

Meaning $M$ is a skew-symmetric matrix, thus it's singular for sure.

Is it correct?

Comment: Why do you claim that a skew-symmetric matrix is “singular for sure”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the Determinant of skew symmetric matrix is always 0, it comes from the fact that the diagonal of skew symmetric matrice is all zeros

Comment: Counter example: $$ A =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$ with determinat $det(A) = 1 $. That all diagonal entries are zero does only imply: $$tr(A) = \sum_{k} \lambda_k = 0$$.

Comment: What about $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$?

Comment: oh, thank you, I will think of something else

Comment: Note that if $A$ is skew-symmetric then $x^T A x = 0$ for all $x$. (Proof idea: Since $x^T A x$ is a scalar, it is equal to its own transpose.)

Comment: thank you @littleO

Comment: If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then what you were trying to prove is correct when $n$ is odd, but, as previous comments showed, it can fail when $n$ is even. The point is that, for odd $n$ (but not for even $n$), all antisymmetric matrices are singular.